# ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine when i am doing import tensorflow_addons as tfa

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

> > when i am installing tensorflow- addons using below code

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

> > then it shows

```
requirement already satisfied as tensorflow flow version 2.10.0
```

> > when i am running this command which is shown below

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

> > it show the error shown below hw to resolve this error

```
C:\Users\AKANKSHA BALI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\utils\ensure_tf_install.py:67: UserWarning: Tensorflow Addons supports using Python ops for all Tensorflow versions above or equal to 2.3.0 and strictly below 2.5.0 (nightly versions are not supported). 
 The versions of TensorFlow you are currently using is 1.15.0 and is not supported. 
Some things might work, some things might not.
If you were to encounter a bug, do not file an issue.
If you want to make sure you're using a tested and supported configuration, either change the TensorFlow version or the TensorFlow Addons's version. 
You can find the compatibility matrix in TensorFlow Addon's readme:
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  UserWarning,
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-8e92e93ce06e>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow_addons as tfa

  File "C:\Users\AKANKSHA BALI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow_addons import activations

  File "C:\Users\AKANKSHA BALI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\activations\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_addons.activations.gelu import gelu

  File "C:\Users\AKANKSHA BALI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\activations\gelu.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow_addons.utils import types

  File "C:\Users\AKANKSHA BALI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\utils\types.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine' (C:\Users\AKANKSHA BALI\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Your current Tensorflow Version is `1.15.0`, the error message says that you need tensorflow version between `2.3.0` and  `2.5.0` and nightly versions are not supported. Try upgrading your tensorflow package by using the command `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested as above?